# How to create table inside a table with full width?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to create a collapsible table like the image below, you can see on click of any row it will expand like the `profile group 6`

[image]

And I made this `Row` component

```js
  <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Profile Group 1</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>2342321</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style={{ width: "100%", padding: 0 }} colSpan={6}>
            <table style={{ width: "100%" }}>
              <tr>
                <td>Visa</td>
                <td>2131243214</td>
                <td>John Doe</td>
                <td>800321</td>
                <td>06/2000</td>
                <td>icon</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Visa</td>
                <td>2131243214</td>
                <td>John Doe</td>
                <td>800321</td>
                <td>06/2000</td>
                <td>icon</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Visa</td>
                <td>2131243214</td>
                <td>John Doe</td>
                <td>800321</td>
                <td>06/2000</td>
                <td>icon</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

then I implemented the above component to this

```js
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
          <div className={styles.tableContainerDiv}>
            <table className={styles.mainTable}>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <td>Name</td>
                  <td>Card Number</td>
                  <td>Card Holder</td>
                  <td>ZIP Code</td>
                  <td>Expiration Date</td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <Row />
            </table>
          </div>
        </Grid>
```

```css
.tableContainerDiv {
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: calc(100vh - 105px);

  .mainTable {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 10px;
    // margin-top: -10px; /* correct offset on first border spacing if desired */

    tr {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    td {
      border: 1px solid $secondary-black;
      border-style: solid none;
      padding: 10px;
      background: $secondary-black;
    }
    td:first-child {
      border-left-style: solid;
      border-top-left-radius: 10px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    }

    td:last-child {
      border-right-style: solid;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
      border-top-right-radius: 10px;
      text-align: right;
    }

    tr,
    td,
    th {
      text-align: left;
      height: 20px;
    }
  }
}
```

And the result I get is this
[image]

So my question is , how to I make that kind of table (image at the top)?

Codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-hypatia-41n3c?file=/src/app.module.scss

Comment: Isn't the result the same as the image above ?

Comment: @Zohir Salak no it isn't, see carefully, the columns are misplaced and there's gap between them

Comment: Oh you want them to line up, Could you put up a working code snippet people can work with ?

Comment: @Zohir Salak Well I give the code above, you check it and right I don't have electricity

Comment: We'd love to help you, But we can't put up any arbitrary code because it may differ from your set up

Comment: @Zohir Salak wait let me explain again, I am using React, the first code is component named "Row" and the second code with styles is the main code where I am importing the component "Row" , and I am using material UI `Grid` , so it will be like `<Grid container> main code </Grid>` and the style is scss module so you have to make a scss module and import it to the main, did you get it?

Comment: @ZohirSalak https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-hypatia-41n3c?file=/src/app.module.scss

Comment: apply `table-layout:fixed` to both tables

Comment: @ZohirSalak so it fixes the layout, but what about the gap between profile group and details below it, check the codesandbox link I have updated the code

Comment: the class `.mainTable` is applying  `border-spacing: 0 10px;` reduce it to `0` you might want to manipulate the border radius afterward to make look seamless

Comment: @ZohirSalak well I want  gaps between the header and profile group(rows), that's why it's there, but I want to remove spacing between the `profile group` and details(visa) below it specifically

Comment: Yes make a new selector for the header alone and add the space below it, your current selector is selecting both

Comment: @ZohirSalak I tried that but it applies to every border , can you make the edit on codesandbox and share the link

Comment: Oh right, your setup doesn't allow for that, Your best bet is to still reduce border-spacing to zero and add an empty `<tr>` below the first one. https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-elgamal-sz185